# Computing Packages for the Generalised Lambert W Function

Tags: statistics, special-functions, computational-mathematics, programming

I have been working on the application of Lambert W Function in statistics. I would like to know whether there are any existing computing packages to compute the Generalised Lambert W Function?

Comment: I would enjoy to find one.

Comment: Scott et al. give hints for algorithms: "Asymptotic series of Generalized Lambert W Function", "Numerics of the Generalized Lambert W Function".